# PropelBundle Installation On Symfony 2.1

Tags: php, symfony, propel, symfony-2.1

I'm trying to install the PropelBundle branch 1.1 on Symfony 2.1. I followed the instructions for a manual install, but not sure where to register the namespaces anymore.

Now I get this error message: `Fatal error: Class 'Propel\PropelBundle\PropelBundle' not found in D:\www-files\Symfony\app\AppKernel.php on line 22`

Line 22 looks like this: `new Propel\PropelBundle\PropelBundle()`

And my autoload.php looks like this:

```
use Doctrine\Common\Annotations\AnnotationRegistry;

$loader = require __DIR__.'/../vendor/autoload.php';

// intl
if (!function_exists('intl_get_error_code')) {
    require_once __DIR__.'/../vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/Locale/Resources/stubs/functions.php';

    $loader->add('', __DIR__.'/../vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/Locale/Resources/stubs');
}

AnnotationRegistry::registerLoader(array($loader, 'loadClass'));

return $loader;
```

Should I add something to the autoload.php?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add the following in composer.json

```
"require" :  {
   .....
    "propel/propel-bundle" :  "1.1.*" 
} ,
```

And run

```
php composer.phar update propel/propel-bundle
```

the tutorial is 
http://www.mon-code.net/article/45/initialisation-dun-projet-symfony-2-1-avec-un-depot-git-et-composer

Comment: It may be obvious to some, but you should point WHERE the "require" part should be added, in this case, composer.json.

Comment: It should be in Symfony/composer.json